# Как осуществить привязку в ControlTemplate?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Писал контрол. Сначала делал так

```
<ContentControl [тут всякая лабуда с определением класса и пространствами имен] DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}">
    <ContentControl.ResourceDictionary>
        <local:Conv1 x:Key="Conv1"/>
    </ContentControl.ResourceDictionary>
    <Border>
        <Border.Width>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Conv1}">
                <Binding Path="Property1"/>
                <Binding Path="Property2"/>
            <MultiBinding>
        </Border.Width>
    </Border>
</ContentControl>
```

Затем я понял, что в корне ошибался, когда избрал этот путь :)

Сделал так.

```
<ContentControl [тут всякая лабуда] DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}">
    <ContentControl.ResourceDictionary>
        <local:Conv1 x:Key="Conv1"/>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border>
                            <Border.Width>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Conv1}">
                                    <Binding Path="Property1"/>
                                    <Binding Path="Property2"/>
                                <MultiBinding>
                            </Border.Width>
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.ResourceDictionary>
</ContentControl>
```

А как теперь мне обратиться к Property1 и Property2?

Comment: Эээ... А зачем вы используете `ContentControl`? Может быть, вам нужен реально `UserControl`? И ещё, где у вас определены свойства `Property1` и `Property2`?

Comment: @VlaD, Свойства определены в наследнике от ContentControl. Я постарался показать это, указав DataContext

Comment: @VladD, а зачем вместо ContentControl использовать UserControl? И как вы делаете подсветку текста серым? :)

Comment: Из интуиции. Мне в жизни приходилось писать сотни `UserControl`'ов, и ни одного производного класса от `ContentControl`'а. Впрочем, правильный ответ зависит от точной семантики. Что именно вы хотите сделать и почему выбрали именно `ContentControl`?

Comment: Попробуйте обратные кавычки. Или нажмите на ссылку «справка» справа от поля для комментирования :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался.

вместо `<Style TargetType="ContentControl">` надо было написать `<Style TargetType="local:ClassName">`. Само собой `local` - это текущее пространство имен (в котором определен класс), а `ClassName` это имя класса.